# Is a gravity or spring damper sufficient for a make up air vent?

Tags: hvac, ventilation, ducts

I am planning on installing a make up air vent in my cold air return. I don't want to install an electric system that I have to wire to 3-4 different appliances. Is a gravity or spring loaded damper sufficient to use in this scenario? I'm assuming it would just open and bring in the make up air when something is turned on that would cause negative air pressure.

Comment: In my opinion, the average house is not nearly airtight enough for the this function.   You’d need a pressure test to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question and I would say it depends. I'm not saying it is impossible, but as you have pointed out these devices operate on static pressure. I am just wondering if it is commercially viable and if anyone makes one that would work in your scenario. It would have to open under very light pressure differences and I don't know of any manufacturer who has one for this purpose. I know this is the same principal as an economizer in a RTU, but they are mechanical.

May be someone more experienced in the mechanics of air flow knows about one.

Good luck.

Comment: Do you think something like an HRV would be better suited for this?

Comment: Could be It's just not my expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use gravity dampers they are less expensive and last longer than spring or powered dampers unless you use fire rated powered dampers at 20 × the cost of a gravity damper.
Spring dampers work but need cleaning in my experiance after 3-4 years. So for a no hassle long life make up air system I use gravity. Make sure to feed your makeup air in the duct before the air filter or add a filter you don't want outside dust getting into your fire box.